# Mysql select into array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm basically trying to simply select from a table into an array...and it's not working correctly.

I have the following query

```
$graph = mysql_query("SELECT MONTHNAME(dateadded) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM products
WHERE ((YEAR(dateadded)=2012) && (site_url = '$_GET[site_url_graph]'))
GROUP BY MONTH(dateadded)",$db);
```

and I need to the results to be in an array like this (can be long or short month name thats not the issue):

```
$data = array(
    'Jan' => 12,
    'Feb' => 25,
    'Mar' => 0,
    'Apr' => 7,
    'May' => 80,
    'Jun' => 67,
    'Jul' => 45,
    'Aug' => 66,
    'Sep' => 23,
    'Oct' => 23,
    'Nov' => 78,
    'Dec' => 6
);
```

I'm trying this but getting message that not an array:

```
$data = array();
while($graphData = mysql_fetch_array($graph)){
    $data[] = $graphData;
    }
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix but tearing hair out here!

Comment: have you tryed running the query in phpmyadmin? what error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your expected array, you need to change your code following way.

```
$data = array();
while($graphData = mysql_fetch_array($graph)){
    $data[$graphData['MONTH']] = $graphData['COUNT'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$graph = mysql_query("SELECT MONTHNAME(dateadded) MONTH, COUNT(*) COUNT
                      FROM products
                      WHERE ((YEAR(dateadded)=2012) && (site_url = '$_GET[site_url_graph]'))
                      GROUP BY MONTH(dateadded)",$db);

$data = array();
while(list($month, $count) = mysql_fetch_array($graph)) {
    $data[$month] = $count; 
}
```

So, basically this is the fast and breezy version of what you want. Notice the usage of list. Nice and readable.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is the problem:
"`COUNT(*) COUNT`"?
Try to change it to `COUNT(*)`

Comment: No, the query is fine - the error I think is in the last part of question

Comment: What are you getting when 'print_r($graphData)'